# Linking a javascript plugins directory to a jsp page in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi i'm a beginner developer and i'm new to spring mvc.I know how to link an external js file using spring url but how to do something like below using spring url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var plugin_path = '/resources/assets/plugins/';
</script>
```

I think this refers to the plugins folder instead of a specific one so that any plugin can be loaded when needed.

(updated)
If it is something like this

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

I'd do something like

```html
<spring:url value="/resources/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" var="jqueryJs" />
<script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
```

to link that jquery.js file.Instead, i want to link the whole plugins folder.Not just one js file.

Comment: can you explain what you need clearly? load everything inside the '/resources/assets/plugins/' directory without mentioning the file name or keep the '/resources/assets/plugins/' path in a general variable and use that variable to specify the file path that needs to be loaded?

Comment: I updated the post cause its hard to write code here.Please take a look. I'm using a template and I'm stuck here. Here is a snap shot of the code and a note pad that was inside the plugins folder of the template.https://postimg.org/image/6x8xkvmkn/